# Sorting AJAX response result in ascending order

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, response

Each time the page is reloaded there is a distortion in the arrangement of the fund names. The name should always arrange like fundI fundII fund III etc. no matter the number of times the page was reloaded.

I have tried different styles but no headways. Everything is displaying well but the problem is the distortion in

Here is my code

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({  
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/Prices/GetAllFundNames',
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).done(function(data) {
                $.each(data.result, function(i, ele) {
                    var detail = {};
                    detail.id = ele.FUND_ID;
                    detail.name = ele.FUND_NAME;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/Prices/GetCurrentFundPrice?fundId=' + ele.FUND_ID
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        console.log(data.result);
                        var sortedData = data.result;
                        sortedData.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
                        //var sortedData = data.Result
                        var id = data.result.FundID;
                        detail.price = data.result.UnitPrice;
                        //sortedname = detail.name;
                        var tile = buildTile(detail);
                        $('#tile-holder').append(tile);
                    })
                })
            });


            function buildTile(detail) {
                detail.sort
                return '<ul style="list-style: none;">'
                + '<li>' + detail.name + '</li>'
                + '<li>' + detail.price + '</li>'
                + '<li><a href="#">View History</a></li>'
                + '</ul><hr>';
            }
        });
```

Comment: `sortedData.sort(function(a, b){return (a.FUND_NAME>b.FUND_NAME?1:-1)});`

Comment: @joyBlanks You can't use `-` to compare strings.

Comment: What does `data.result` look like? `return a - b;` will only work if it's an array of numbers. But if it's an array of numbers, what is `data.result.FundID` and `data.result.UnitPrice` supposed to be, that requires it to be an object.

Comment: @joyBlanks that's a questionable comparison function because it ignores the possibility of equal keys. Better to use `.localeCompare()` which returns exactly the right sort of value.

Comment: The `.sort()` callback is indeed wrong, but the most important problem is that the sort needs to happen *after* all the ajax calls have completed.

Comment: @joyBlanks I tried `sortedData.sort(function(a, b){return (a.FUND_NAME>b.FUND_NAME?1:-1)});`  but got  ` Uncaught TypeError: sortedData.sort is not a function

Comment: If there is any other way. When I checked the endpoint on the swagger UI. The response wasn't changing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As commented by @Pointy, it's best to use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to order a string.

```js
...done(function(data) {
  var sortedData = [];
  for (var i in data.result) sortedData.push(data.result[i]);
  sortedData.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
  });
  ...
```

and seems you have an error in this function:

```
        function buildTile(detail) {
            detail.sort
            return ...
```

Comment: `data.result` is object

Comment: do you wanna sort the object by what exactly? if you wanna use the properties name you can make that array with `Object.keys(data.result);`

Comment: I want to sort by name fundI fund II Fund III

Comment: "by name" as in `data.result[item].name` ? then you just got to update your sort function. check the updated answer

Comment: I am getting `sorted.html:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined`

Comment: you gotta make sure all your items have a string in the name attribute. You can use an if statement to add an empty string if the name is undefined.